# Want a deeper understanding of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here's my sample code for a programming problem asking to split a string and sort the individual words to avoid duplicates. I know that this code is 100% correct, but I'm not really sure what the purpose of `lst = list()` line of code is?

How does the program know to put the file romeo in the list?

```
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
romeo = open(fname)
lst = list()
for line in romeo:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.split()
    for e in line:
        if e not in lst:
            lst.append(e)
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

Comment: It's so you have a list to hold your answers in...

Comment: You can also use `lst=[]` to define it to be an empty list.

Comment: it's the same as `lst = []`

Comment: Sorry @patrick ....

Comment: Read the first paragraph: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=list#list and then you can read about `append` here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: By the way, if you need `line.split()` without an argument, you do not need to do `line.rstrip()`.

Comment: @rnso story of my life...

Comment: You can also do all of this like that: `lst = sorted(set(sum(line.split() for line in romeo)))`

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Does `sum` really belong there?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Aha, we can do this: `lst = sorted(set(sum((line.split() for line in romeo),[])))`

Comment: @ Arndt Jonasson, thanks I forgot the `[]`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The purpose of `lst = list()` is to create an instance of **list**  called *lst*.

You could also replace it by

```
lst = []
```

it's exactely the same.

The line `lst.append(e)` is filling it. [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_append.htm) more about the **append** method

Comment: You create an instance of list and call it lst

Comment: Calling it a declaration is not correct - you could perfectly well assign a non-list to `lst` later.

Comment: You're perfectly right guys, I correct it right now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are confused with iteration over the file. Iteration allows us to treat the file as a container which can be iterated just like we do for any other container like list or set or dict.items().

Also `lst = list()` means `lst = []`. This has got nothing to do with file iteration.

Answer (score 0):

List is a python object. Type help(list) in your interpreter. You would see your screen

[image: Help on list]

Usually for some programming languages calling className() would create object of the type class. For example in C++

```
class MyClass{
      var declarations
      method definitions
}
MyObj=MyClass()
```

The MyObj in above code is object for your class MyClass. Apply same thing for your code **lst is object type of list class** that is predefined in Python which we call it as builtin data structure.

So your above lst definition would initialize lst to be a empty list.

The help section shows two types of constructors for list class those are used in different ways. The second type of constructor

```
list(iterable)
```

would create a list with already created sequence. For example

```
tuple1=(1,'mars')
new_list=list(tuple1)
print(new_list)
```

would create new list new_list using the tuple which is a iterable.

Comment: @PNW_DataAnalyst. Does the answer makes sense. please let me know for further discussion

Answer (score 0):

See below for more insights:

```
# the following line stores your input in fname as a str
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
# the following line opens the file named fname and stores it in romeo
romeo = open(fname)
# next line creates an empty list through the built in function list()
lst = list()
# now you go through all the lines in the file romeo
# each word is assigned to the variable line sequentially
for line in romeo:
# strip the line of evntual withespaces at the end of the string
    line = line.rstrip()
# split the string on withespaces and stores each element
# of the splitted string in the list line which will then contain every
# word of the line.
    line = line.split()
# now you go through all the elements in the list line
# each word is assigned to e sequentially
    for e in line:
# now if the word is not contained in the list lst
        if e not in lst:
# it inserts the word to the list in the last postion of the list lst.
            lst.append(e)
# sort the list alphabetically            
lst.sort()
print(lst)
```

Some notes:

- you would probably want to add `romeo.close()` at the end of the script to close the file
- it is important to note that not all the file will be stored in the lst list. Each word will be stored there only once thanks to `if e not in lst:`